# Install all modules artifacts to custom maven repository using Gradle and Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a pure Java lib that I use in my Android project, I'm trying to configure it so when I run 'gradle install' it will build the entire project and install all the artifacts to a custom local repository which is evidently a git repository.

**This is the module gradle file, the project builds fine:**

```
group 'com.packagenaem'
def artifact = 'artifactname'
version '1.0.0'
apply plugin: 'java'

def MAVEN_LOCAL_PATH = 'file:///some/path/to/my/repo'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        apply plugin: 'maven'
        mavenInstaller {
            repository(url: MAVEN_LOCAL_PATH)
            pom.groupId = group
            pom.artifactId = artifact
            pom.version = version
            pom.packaging = 'jar'
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

**The error I get when running from command line is:**

```
Could not find method repository() for arguments [{url=file:///some/path/to/my/repo}] on repository container
```

If I omit this line `repository(url: MAVEN_LOCAL_PATH)` then it installs all the artifacts very nicely to the /users/$USER/.m2/repository

**=== UPDATE ===**

After playing with it a bit when executing the following `gradle uploadArchive`, I got to a point where I get the following error:

```
Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository remote (/some/path/to/my/custom/repo) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

**==== EXTENDING THIS QUESTION A BIT ====**

So since I've already set a bounty for this question, lets extend it and ask how can I make it so that I'll write the above code once in my project  gradle file and upon "gradle uploadArchives" it will deploy the artifacts of all projects? currently I've duplicated all the code cross all the build gradle files I have and I hate this sort of solution...

Comment: Using mavenInstaller or mavenDeployer both does not do the trick... the only difference is that mavenDeployer complies with the repository but ignores it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so I've wasted a lot of time and brain cells on this one...

Instead of declaring:

```
repository(url: file("/some/path/to/my/custom/repo"))
```

Change it to:

```
repository url: 'file://' + new File("/some/path/to/my/custom/repo").absolutePath
```

I have no idea why but now every configuration I try works...

Comment: There is a function that will create a URL for a file for you: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:uri(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Take a look at [org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileOrUriNotationConverter#convert](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/478a891a864c8749c194d42c52973cb1c8dfa8a7/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/file/FileOrUriNotationConverter.java#L57) for how gradle is actually parsing the string. If you look at [the maven plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:deploying_to_a_maven_repository) if you would have just done `repository(url: 'file://some/path/to/my/custom/repo')`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mavenInstaller` have you tried `mavenDeployer`?
According to [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) it supports what you want to do.

EDIT:
Have you tried combining `mavenDeployer` with:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url MAVEN_LOCAL_PATH
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not do the trick because eventually it does not install the artifact to the custom folder.

Comment: That is strange... see the edit I made, I found that while looking for something else.. I hope that it helps you :)

Comment: Also please note that I'm trying to install the artifact to a custom repo and not the default local repo

Comment: Place it before or after `uploadArchives `. I thought that the logic behind it would be similar to publishing to a remote repo.. but I guess I was wrong. I saw somewhere that you can edit your `settings.xml` file to change the default local repo, you can always try that, even if it is just for testing :)

Comment: I don't' know what changed, but all of a sudden it works all the time... I've reverted to the first moment before posting this, and now it works... I didn't change anything in the file and checked for typos, nothing... really weird joojoo